# How to copy item attachment to another item through Rest api or JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, attachments, sharepoint-list

I have a list item with attachments. I want to copy this attachment to another item using JSOM or REST API.
Anyone suggest an idea to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The following code for your reference. Tested the code. its working

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var listName="CL1120";
var sourceItemId=1;
var targetItemId=2;
 
function getAttachments() {   
    var requestUri = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + sourceItemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
    // execute AJAX request
    return $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" }       
    });
}
function copyAttachments(){
    getAttachments().done(function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
            //var fileUrl=item.ServerRelativeUrl;
            var targetFileName=item.FileName;
            var sourceSiteUrlList = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+sourceItemId+")/AttachmentFiles/getbyfilename('" + targetFileName + "')/$value";
            var targetSiteUrl = url + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + targetItemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + targetFileName + "')";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', sourceSiteUrlList, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('binaryStringResponseBody', 'true');
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            xhr.onload = function (e) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    var arrayBuffer = this.response;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: targetSiteUrl,
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: arrayBuffer,
                        processData: false,
                        headers: { 'binaryStringRequestBody': 'true', 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8', 'X-RequestDigest':  $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() }
                    }).done(function (postData) {
                            console.log('we did it!');
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, errorText) {
                            //alert(errorText.statusText);
                    });
                }
            }
            xhr.send();         
        }); 
    }); 
}
</script>
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="copyAttachments()" value="Copy Attachments"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is copying the attachments with the same name. but the file is not properly creating. if I have one .txt file with content means, new file have some XML content, not the same text content.     -  any idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

Append `$value` at the end of the URL to get the file attachment

```
var sourceSiteUrlList = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+sourceItemId +")/AttachmentFiles/getbyfilename('" + fileName + "')/$value";
```

This seems to fix the issue of corrupted files with non text files.